# In Ember.js, is it possible to force computed properties defined on a route to update when the model refreshes?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, computed-properties

In Ember.js, is it possible to force computed properties defined on a route to update when the model refreshes?

I am noticing that the first time I hit a route, I will see the functions that back computed properties invoked, but if the route's model is refreshed because a query parameter (e.g. `page`) changes, the functions backing the computed properties are not invoked again. I assume that this is because Ember doesn't believe the computed properties to have changed, in part because it doesn't believe the properties they are dependent on to have changed. For example:

```
// routes/example.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  limit: 10,
  queryParams: {
    page: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },

  offset: computed("limit", function() {
    console.log("IN: offset");
    let params = this.paramsFor(this.get("routeName"));
    if (params.page) {
      // calculate offset using the "params.page" value
    }
    return 0;
  }),

  paginator: computed("limit", "offset", "query", function() {
    console.log("IN: paginator");
    // Calls: this.get("offset") and this.get("query") as part of its invocation
    // Returns an object that can resolve the pagination of the model.
    ...
  }),

  query: computed(function() {
    console.log("IN: query");
    ...
  }),

  model(params) {
    console.log("IN: model");
    let paginator = this.get("paginator");
    ...
  },

  setupController(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.setProperties({
      offset: this.get("offset"),
      limit: this.get("limit"),
      pageCount: model.meta.total,
    });
  }
});
```

... and the controller:

```
// controllers/example.js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  actions: {

    firstPage: function() {
      this.transitionToRoute({
        queryParams: {
          page: 1
        }
      });
    },

    lastPage: function() {
      let lastPage = Math.ceil(this.get('pageCount')/this.get('limit'));
      this.transitionToRoute({
        queryParams: {
          page: lastPage
        }
      });
    },

    nextPage: function() {
      let totalPages = Math.ceil(this.get('pageCount')/this.get('limit'));
      if(this.incrementProperty('page') > totalPages) {
         this.set('page', totalPages);
      }

      this.transitionToRoute({
        queryParams: {
          page: this.get('page')
        }
      });
    },

    previousPage: function() {
      if(this.decrementProperty('page') < 1) {
        this.set('page', 1);
      }

      this.transitionToRoute({
        queryParams: {
          page: this.get('page')
        }
      });
    }
  },

  ...

  /**
   * The result page that a user is currently viewing.
   */
  page: 1,

  /**
   * The query parameters.
   */
  queryParams: ["page"],

});
```

The first time I load the route by hitting the associated URL in the browser I see:

```
IN: model
IN: paginator
IN: offset
IN: query
```

If I click on a button in the rendered template which changes the `?page` query param, such as with the `nextPage` action, I see that it calls in to refresh the model but does not invoke any of the logic behind the computed properties, e.g.:

```
IN: model
```

I've tried adding `controller.page` to the list of dependent properties, but this does not seem to change the observed behavior. As an aside, functions appear to always be called (as I would expect).

Should I not be using computed properties in the route? It seems like if I want to use computed properties I need to somehow notify Ember to re-process them when the model is refreshed whether Ember believes them to have changed or not.

Comment: Instead of 'offset' use 'page' for dependant property for computer. And one more thing you don't need to call transitionToRoute explicitly instead just setting controller page property is enough

Comment: Either move computed properties to controller or move page property from controller to route and set page property of the route. Either case your offset computed property should depends on the page property

Comment: One thing to keep in mind your cp `query` will be evaluated once and will never change as there is no dependent key.

Comment: @kumkanillam: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll refactor some and give those a shot to see if I can make it work.

Comment: @kitler yeah, I should probably watch for page and/or additional query params there as well, based on Kumkanillam's suggestions above. Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to solve this ?